# open PDF in my webview and make phone call through it

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, phone-call

i want to open pdf in my webview and if that pdf contains any phone number then i can make call when touches on phone number.any help please?

Comment: any other way for this? can i do it without webview?

Answer (score 0):

If the PDF is on the web just load the page in the webview or you can use phonegap ([phonegap.com](http://phonegap.com)) if you want to load a local PDF.  If you choose the first option just go into interface builder and check the phone numbers checkbox from your webviews info.  On phone gap phone numbers are standard